# Sometimes, the asio::tcp::socket object gets closed automatically before calling shutdown/close

Tags: sockets, c++11, boost-asio, asio

Once in 5 times, I get this "Bad file descriptor"error when I am attempting to shutdown or close the asio::ip::tcp::socket object. The following is the function to close the acceptor and socket.

```
void close_server()
{
    acceptor_instance.close(error_code);
    if (error_code)
    {
        std::cerr << "close_server(): acceptor::close()" << "Error: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
    }        
    if(socket_instance.is_open())
    {
        socket_instance.shutdown(asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, error_code);
        if (error_code)
        {
            std::cerr << "close_server(): socket::close()" << "Error: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
        }
        socket_instance.close(error_code);
        if (error_code)
        {
            std::cerr << "close_server(): socket::close()" << "Error: " << error_code.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "close_server(): socket_instance is already CLOSED" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Sometimes the socket_intance.is_open() fails. Attempting to call the socket.shutdown() or socket.close() without checking if the socket is open, gives "Bad file descriptor" error, that means the socket was already closed.

**How to identify the cause?**

**How to know when it was closed?**

Comment: *You* closed it somewhere else, probably in response to an error or end of stream, which is correct programming. It doesn't just get closed sponaneously by itself. I don't see why you're concerned about a single socket instance at all at this point. Surely you may have more than one client? The correct way to close the server is to close the accepting socket and let all the existing client connections close themselves in due course, probably with a timeout to help them along.

Comment: If you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I will look at it to understand the context

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I just have one client involved here.

Comment: @sehe I will try to elaborate my setup. I have a library that uses ASIO library for the Async communication. In order to test certain behavior, I have written a Test_Server class, that uses ASIO library. The test case basically, starts the client and waits for the connection. Meanwhile, the test server is started on another thread and accepts the connection. I join the test server thread once the test is completed.